# iCloud stuck on 'uploading 311 items'

Tags: iphone, ios, icloud

I'm running an iPhone 6S Plus on iOS 9.0.1 and am having problem syncing all of my photos with iCloud - it's been stuck for almost a week now and won't upload any more photos, even though I have around 3GB of free space.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/Zd9h5.png

Is there anything you could recommend please? I was going to stop the sync and restart it again but it warns me that I may lose some files, and since almost all of them are photos and videos of my cat who passed away today I'm terrified of losing them :(

Thank you

Comment: Do you have a computer that you could backup your photos to?

Comment: Hi @bassplayer7, yes I do